# How to create a .NET Core library that is Multi-Targeting but targets different dll's per framework?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, multi-targeting

I'm trying to update a library that is currently targeting .NET4.0 to:

- NETStandard 2.0
- NET4.5.2

using Multi-Targeting.

The dependent library I'm using is `Microsoft.Build.Framework`. It's found either in two places:

- [`NuGet`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.Framework/) and min level is NET4.6
- GAC via Full Framework (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll`)

Because the nuget package min level is above 4.5.2, I can't use that nuget package in the 452 target.

So, is it possible to say:
- When using NS20, please use the nuget package.
- When using NET4.5.2, please use the GAC version.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your dependencies conditionally, depending on what *current* target framework the project is being built on. For that, you would adjust your project file to use the NuGet dependencies in one case, or standard non-NuGet references in the other case.

That would look like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- other properties -->
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net452</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- common references -->
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net452'">
     <Reference Include="Microsoft.Build.Framework" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net452'">
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Framework" Version="15.7.179" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

So `net452` would get the normal assembly reference `Microsoft.Build.Framework` with the [`Reference` element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items#reference), which can be resolved from the GAC or the local directory, and other frameworks will resolve it from NuGet using a [`PackageReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files).

Answer (score 1):

The trick is modify your `csproj` and specify *manually* the packages to use under either specific framework.

So here's what I ended up doing. Take note of:

- `PackageReference`: get this from NuGet.
- `Reference`: get this from your GAC.

.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net452</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0' ">
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Framework" Version="15.7.179" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core" Version="15.7.179" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net452' ">
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.Build.Framework" Version="15.7.179" />
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0" Version="15.7.179" />
</ItemGroup>
```

So here, we are getting the packages from NuGet if the framework is `NS20` while we try and get them from the GAC if it's for `NET452`.

Winner winner, chicken dinner!